# How can I do an operation only for one value on the fly in a numpy array? (or the better way)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array e.g. `a = np.arange(0, 5)` and it looks like this `array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])`.

Now what I want to do is e.g. to add only at the index 2 a value like 5 and get a new numpy array object.

Like this: `b = add_value_on_idx(a, 2, 5) # This should return a new object`

I have tried this approaches to achieve this

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.5

import numpy as np

from time import time

# Get a numpy array first
a = np.random.randint(0, 10, (5, ))

# Define a new tuple of zeros with only one number at the
# specific index
def do_add_at_idx_1(arr, idx, val):
    return arr+(((0, )*(idx))+(val, )+(0, )*(arr.shape[0]-idx-1))

# Or do it like this
def do_add_at_idx_2(arr, idx, val):
    one_val_vec = np.zeros((arr.shape[0], )).astype(arr.dtype)
    one_val_vec[idx] = val
    return arr+one_val_vec

# Or add it directly to the given array
def do_add_at_idx_3(arr, idx, val):
    arr = arr.copy()
    arr[idx] += val
    return arr

# Or use directly np.add.at function (but need a copy first)
def do_add_at_idx_4(arr, idx, val):
    arr = arr.copy()
    np.add.at(arr, idx, val)
    return arr

a_old = a.copy()
print("a: {}".format(a))
print("do_add_at_idx_1(a, 2, 5): {}".format(do_add_at_idx_1(a, 2, 5)))
print("do_add_at_idx_2(a, 2, 5): {}".format(do_add_at_idx_2(a, 2, 5)))
print("do_add_at_idx_3(a, 2, 5): {}".format(do_add_at_idx_3(a, 2, 5)))
print("do_add_at_idx_4(a, 2, 5): {}".format(do_add_at_idx_4(a, 2, 5)))
print("Was 'a' modified? {}".format("No." if np.all(a==a_old) else "YES!!"))
```

Which will output something like this:

```
a: [6 6 9 2 8]
do_add_at_idx_1(a, 2, 5): [ 6  6 14  2  8]
do_add_at_idx_2(a, 2, 5): [ 6  6 14  2  8]
do_add_at_idx_3(a, 2, 5): [ 6  6 14  2  8]
do_add_at_idx_4(a, 2, 5): [ 6  6 14  2  8]
Was 'a' modified? No.
```

I have also tested the time differences for these functions too:

```
n = 100000
print("n: {}".format(n))
idxs = np.random.randint(0, a.shape[0], (n, ))
vals = np.random.randint(0, 10, (n, ))

for i in range(1, 5):
    func_name = "do_add_at_idx_{}".format(i)
    func = globals()[func_name]

    start = time()
    for idx, val in zip(idxs, vals):
        func(a, idx, val)
    delta = time()-start

    print("Taken time for func '{}': {:2.4f}s".format(func_name, delta))
```

With this as an output:

```
Taken time for func 'do_add_at_idx_1': 2.1899s
Taken time for func 'do_add_at_idx_2': 1.4600s
Taken time for func 'do_add_at_idx_3': 0.5757s
Taken time for func 'do_add_at_idx_4': 2.8043s
```

Are there any better ways to do this approach?

Comment: Version 3 looks the sanest, fastest and best, and is how I would do it. But remember: Copying is expensive, so it would be even better if you could modify in place, without creating a new array.

Comment: I know, but I ask this question for seeing, if there is actually a better way to do this. But you are right, in place modifying **is** faster.

Comment: I don't think there is. I do not know any special way to do this, and usually the straighforward way with numpy functions (without conversions to lists or tuples) is the best. And there is hardly anything in the copy+modify solution which you could optimize away.